# Is plugging a leading-edge dimmable lamp into a trailing-edge dimmer plug safe?

Tags: electrical, safety, dimmer-switch

**Rationale for what I'm trying to do**: I'm trying to update my house to use "smart" lighting and one device I want to update is a smart lamp in [this style](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06WLQXB1J) but with replaceable bulbs. If I switch over all of the bulbs to smart bulbs, then I'll be out a lot of money. I also fear some sort of dangerous consequence to there being a leading edge dimmer on the lamp, so I'm avoiding plugging smart bulbs into it.

Given the above rationale, I'm wondering if I plug the lamp into a "dimmer plug" such as [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000U39QWU) if there will be any severe consequences due to the fact that there is a dimmer switch on the lamp as well. The dimmer switch on the lamp is likely of the leading-edge variety, as it came with incandescent bulbs. I will also plan to use LED bulbs in the lamp and keep the lamp's dimmer slider to its highest setting and only use the smart dimmer plug for controlling the light.

Comment: So you want to use one dimmer switch to power another dimmer switch ? That will not work.

Comment: Can you explain why?  Intuitively it makes sense. If the dinner switch on the lamp is maxed out, then it should not be modulating the flow of electricity at all. Thus the dimmer component on the plug should be able to work, right?

Comment: Except that's not how dimmers work.  Back in the 80s my room's dimmer had a free range of motion which dimmed, and if you pushed down past a detent you got to hard OFF. (for changing bulbs).  But if you pushed up past a detent, you got to hard ON which bypassed the dimmer circuitry and hotshot 120V to the bulb.  It was noticably brighter.  Takeaway: "Dimmer knob to 100%" *does not equal* "whole sinewave".